# Create multiples dataframe from multiples excel files

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am doing some experiments and for each one I get an excel file. Every time I do a experiment I get between 20 and 30 excel files. This is why I try to don't import file by file using pd.read_excel

I'm trying to do a script to import each file into a DataFrame with the original name.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Luis\Desktop\Experiments\Day1\\'
files = os.listdir(path)
file = [x[:-5] for x in files] %delete extension

for f in file:
    f = pd.read_excel(path+f+'.xlsx', 'Analysis with Voltage')
```

I expect a DataFrame for each excel file

I got a DataFrame named f with the last excel file. I can see that the problem is that the variable don't iterate. Any suggestion about how to continue?

Comment: just use a list to keep the dataframes.
`
data = []
for f in file:
    table = pd.read_excel(path+f+'.xlsx', 'Analysis with Voltage')
    data.append(table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_data = []
for f in file:
    all_data.append(pd.read_excel(path+f+'.xlsx', 'Analysis with Voltage'))
```

and if you want to get store dataframes with actual file name then:

```
all_data = dict()
for f in file:
    all_data[f] = pd.read_excel(path+f+'.xlsx', 'Analysis with Voltage')
```

This way you will have f as key for every DataFrame